# On convex polygons contained in convex polygons

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, computational-geometry

In what follows '$n$-gon' stands for '$n$-vertex polygonal region'.

**Question:** Given a convex $n$-gon $C$, find the **smallest** convex region $R$ such that $C$ is the **smallest** $n$-gon that contains it.

**Remarks:** the 2 'smallest' can independently mean either of 'least area' or 'least perimeter' thus we have 2 questions - indeed, since the two 'smallest's in the question are independent, there are 2 further 'mixed' questions which seem less intuitive. It seems that for both (or may be all of these) questions, for any $C$, $R$ has to touch every side of $n$ along a segment - and thus $R$ should have $2n$ vertices. Another question which one can ask is if for any $C$, all or some of the 4 questions have the same $R$ as answer.

Note: If 'smallest' is given other meanings, say 'smallest diameter', there are even more questions in there.

Comment: This might be more interesting with a particular example of $n$ and $C$ and meaning for "smaller"

Comment: Is it clear that a smallest region $R$ exists?  One can construct a sequence of regions $R_1,R_2,\ldots$ such that for each $i$, the $n$-gon $C$ is the smallest $n$-gon containing $R_i$, but the $R_i$'s limit to a region $R$ such that $C$ is *not* the smallest $n$-gon containing $R$.  (Presumably, $R$ would be an $n$-gon with one vertex on each edge of $C$.)  I could imagine that such a sequence approaches the infimum of "size" (in whatever sense we want to say "smallest") and that no smallest $R$ exists.

Comment: That is a possibility I didn't think of. Maybe that may happen if *area* is the criterion; am unable to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

No, the region $R$ does *not* have to touch sides of $C$ along segments; at least if "smallest" understood in terms of perimeter.
Say, for a unit square $C$, the inscribed round disc is a solution.

Indeed, in this case, the average width of $R$ is at least $1$.
Therefore perimeter of $R$ is at least $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks. I understand this implies "the smallest perimeter convex region R for which the unit square is the least perimeter 4-gon containing it is the unit disc".  Hope you could explain the observation that the average width of R has to be at least 1.

Comment: @NandakumarR Consider all circumscribed rectangles. Its perimeter is 4 or more. So average widths in two orthogonal directions have to be at least 1.